# Interactive Zero-Knowledge Proof for the Multiplication Gate

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge

Refer to an interesting article ([link](https://medium.com/web3studio/simple-explanations-of-arithmetic-circuits-and-zero-knowledge-proofs-806e59a79785)) on Medium on the subject matter.

To understand more about pRandomValue and vRandomValue.

The article mentioned, "*pRandomValue, on the other hand, is used to hide (contents of purple box) from Veronica*"

(1) But, Veronica already knows (contents of purple box), so why to hide?

(2) (if for the time being, leaving vRandomValue aside and focusing only on pRandomValue),

Since we want to convert both sides into "Smash" operations, what is wrong in using the following?

"*LHS: (contents of red box) * (contents of purple box) + (contents of red box)*"

and

"*RHS: (contents of yellow box) + (contents of red box)*"